# Android Studio Custom View Issues

Tags: java, android, android-view, android-custom-view

I am in desperate need of help. I have been trying to solve my issues out for days and I am losing any desire to carry on with my project. I just can't seem to understand, so please can you help me do so.

I am trying to create an activity_all_friends.xml that holds a list of friends. My idea was that I would have a linear layout that holds custom views ("friendView").

I have created the friendView:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/friendImage"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="Person Image"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/person2" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/friendName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Name of friend"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/interactionInPersonIcon"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/in_person" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/interactionInPersonText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="299"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/interactionVideoIcon"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:tint="#292828"
                    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/presence_video_online" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/interactionVideoText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="299" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/interactionTextIcon"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/text_icon" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/interactionTextText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="299"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/interactionPhoneIcon"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:tint="#353535"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/phone_icon" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/interactionPhoneText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="299"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Anyway, when I try and draw this new view on my activity_all_friends layout, it appears blank:

[image]

I also want to add these new friends with the click off the "Create New" button on the top right. I have assigned setOnClickListener to the button. The button press is working and the new elements seem to be ceated, I just cannot see them.

My FriendView class:

```
public class FriendView extends LinearLayout {
    private Context context;
    private String friend;

    public FriendView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null,0);
    }

    public FriendView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs,0);
    }

    public FriendView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs,defStyle);
        init(attrs,0);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){

    }

    public String getFriend() {
        return friend;
    }

    public void setFriend(String friend) {
        this.friend = friend;
    }

    public View getView(View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friend_view, null);

        TextView friendName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.friendView);
        TextView interactionInPersonText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.interactionInPersonText);
        TextView interactionVideoText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.interactionVideoText);
        TextView interactionTextText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.interactionTextText);
        TextView interactionPhoneText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.interactionPhoneText);

        // TODO
        friendName.setText("Temp random");
        interactionInPersonText.setText(Long.toString(Math.round(Math.random() * 300)));
        interactionVideoText.setText(Long.toString(Math.round(Math.random() * 300)));
        interactionTextText.setText(Long.toString(Math.round(Math.random() * 300)));
        interactionPhoneText.setText(Long.toString(Math.round(Math.random() * 300)));

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
}
```

Anyone got any ideas as to why this is happening? My understanding is that I need to write the xml element that I want to generate (the friend_view.xml in my case), I want to write the class which dynamically handles what happens to the element (the friendView class in my case), and then I want to link that to the layout where I want it to be generated (the activity_all_friends.xml in my case). Is this correct?

2 other small questions: I have my friends_view.xml in the layout folder, is this correct? Where do the attributes come in (attr.xml)? I want to hit my API and dynamically change the numbers and friends name.

Thanks for all your help!!

Comment: Using a custom `View` for this is rather unusual. What book did you read on Android app development that taught you this approach?

Comment: You might also want to try using Constraint Layout.

Comment: please add `android-studio` tag only if the issue is related to the android studio IDE itself

Comment: @CommonsWare the thinking behind this was that each time a "friend" is created, this whole friend_view object would be rendered. Instead of manually setting all the views that the friend_view are made up of manually in code each time a "friend" is created. Is this not the right approach? Could you suggest something different? I guess the whole point was that I could generate this one element each time instead of all the elements it contains.

Comment: "Is this not the right approach?" -- as I wrote, it is rather unusual. We normally reserve custom views for general-purpose cases, where we need a widget that renders differently than what we have available. Custom views for domain-specific scenarios (friends, restaurants, invoices) are difficult to maintain and test. We tend to use other patterns (e.g., presenters) where we can extract the business logic from the rendering code, for better testability and flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should inflate your layout into your custom view using inflater.inflate(R.layout.friend_view,this,true) without assigning to any variable and you should call this in your init function.

Comment: Thanks, you hit the nail on the head. My use of the inflate method was wrong!